# Change Image in <CardMedia>

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I have an array of images. I would like to update the image in the CardMedia every time the user presses the image.

What I cant figure is how get the next image in the array (current index)?

```
<Grid item xs>
  <Card className={classes.card}>
    <CardHeader
      avatar={
        <Avatar aria-label="Recipe" className={classes.avatar}>
          R
        </Avatar>
      }
      title="Title ....."
      subheader="September 14, 2016"
    />
    <CardMedia
      id="cm"
      className={classes.media}
      image="https://material-ui-next.com/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
      title="Title"
      onClick={this.onClick}
    />
  </Card>
</Grid>

onClick() {
  console.log("** onClick **");
  //How to update the backgroundImage with the next image in the Array ???
  document.getElementById("cm").style["backgroundImage"] =
    "url('./wind/saxophones.jpg')";
}

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    IMAGES: [
      {
        url: "./wind/baritones.jpg"
      },
      {
        url: "./wind/saxophones.jpg"
      },
      {
        url: "./wind/flute-893911__340.jpg"
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start off with imageIndex = 0:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    imageIndex: 0,
    IMAGES: [{
    ...
```

In CardMedia, you need to reference the current selected image using state:

```
<CardMedia
  id='cm'
  className={classes.media}
  image={this.state.IMAGES[this.state.imageIndex]}
  title="Title"
  onClick={this.onClick}
/>
```

Then in your onClick handler:

```
onClick() {
  // now set the image
  this.setState({imageIndex: this.state.imageIndex + 1})
}
```

Lastly, you probably need to bind `this` to your onClick handler:

```
onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: happy to help @angus